# How to form conclusion with logistic regression on leaf infection dataset?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, logistic

I am working on a leaf infection dataset with three groups; wildtype, transgene line 1 and transgene line 2. The infection data i am looking at is coded as a binary variable (1 if the infection was successful, 0 if the infection failed). For every group there are 24 binary datapoints.

```
 head(data)
```

`infection groups
    1         0 group1
    2         0 group1
    3         0 group1
    4         0 group1
    5         0 group1
    6         1 group1`

I am now looking to detect a difference between the groups through hypothesis testing. I made a logistic regression model in R in which I take wildtype as the reference group.

```
glm(formula = infection ~ groups, family = binomial(link = logit), 
    data = zphyto)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.6835  -0.6835  -0.2918  -0.2918   2.5211  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)   -1.3350     0.5026  -2.656  0.00791 **
groupsgroup2  -1.8005     1.1383  -1.582  0.11370   
groupsgroup3  -1.8005     1.1383  -1.582  0.11370   
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

I get the interpretation of the coefficients, but I would now like to formulate my answer e.g. the chance of being infected is bigger in wildtype than in group 3.
Is this possible? Because there seems to be an indication, but the coefficients of group2 and group3 are not significant at the 0.05 level.

Comment: This isn't clear & isn't very answerable at present. What, exactly, are you asking? What would it mean to "formulate [your] answer e.g. the chance of being infected is bigger in wildtype than in group 3"? Are you asking about the significance? Do you want to compute the risk difference? Something else? Can you post the full output?

Comment: And also tell us why the two transgene groups give the same coefficient to 4 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving this answer based on my reasoning that you are effectively asking whether you can state that there is a difference, in terms of the log odds of infection, between your reference group (wildtype) and the remaining two groups (transgender lines 1 and 2).

Based on your model's summary table, using the conventional p < .05 as the cut-off point, you cannot say that there is a difference between the reference group and any of the remaining two groups. Thus, you should *fail to reject* your null hypothesis. You could interpret this as no significant difference between the reference group and the remaining two groups, which can be a finding in itself.